# Why is my laptop's graphics performance going down when it is connected with AC power?

Tags: laptop, performance

My HP Omen (Windows 10, Core i7 7th gen, 16GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 6GB) was so far working great to render even high-end games and applications on high FPS. But now, I am facing problem even with moderate level games and applications.

Before anyone can think of damaged hardware because of heat, let me tell you the peculiarity of the problem: I am experiencing this problem only when the laptop is connected with AC power, not on battery. It's quite opposite of what I expected. It's bad for me because running a high end game and application on battery drains the battery fast.

I have already checked the power options and all graphics options. Graphics card isn't being throttled down when on AC power.

What's actually happening? How to fix this?

Comment: How are you actually measuring performance? You should try Unigine Heaven(or other) and give the data of the benchmark.

Comment: does this ring a bell? https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Gaming-Notebooks/Throttled-Performance-from-AC-Adapter/td-p/4885341

Comment: @wmz Wow.. Exactly the same issue, but on older machine.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with HP laptops, but with Dell laptops, if you're using an underpowered AC adapter, the system will throttle down, even with a full battery charge.

Are you using the original AC Adapter?  Do you have a 2nd AC adapter to try?  It's possible that your AC Adapter isn't putting out the full amperage needed.

Comment: Looks like my adapter got damaged by over voltage or something. I used adapter of my old laptop and problem is gone. Thanks.